# How to configure Jest and babel-jest for specific folder

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm getting the following error:

```
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The reason is that some module/s are not been compiled when published in npm.

I was wondering, how I can include them in the babel-jest compilation specific node_modules folder?

This is my current configuration in the package.json

```
"jest": {
    "silent": false,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(scss|css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/localStorageMock.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
```

I didn't find any solution in the documentation. It would be great if I can do something like this or something similar, adding which folder/s to transform:

```
"transformPaths": [ "path/to/file.js", "path/to/file.jsx"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got some help from the Jest guys,
[Here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react-native.html#transformignorepatterns-customization) is how to do it